Rmd (No shiny): using ggiraph- display filtered data table
I try to setup an Rmd to get rendered in html (thus no shiny is allowed) .
I use ggiraph and crosstalk packages to create interactive plots.
I need to show the filtered table when a point on a plot is selected (similar to plotly).
I found a relevant example here, but it requires shiny: run_girafe_example("DT")
server.R
    library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot_ <- renderGirafe({
    data <- mtcars
    data$label <- gsub(pattern = "'", " ", row.names(data) )
    data$onclick <- paste0("set_search_val(\"", data$label, "\");")
    p <- ggplot(aes(x=wt, y=mpg,
                    tooltip = label,
                    data_id = label, onclick = onclick ),data=data) +
      geom_point_interactive(size = 3) + theme_minimal()

    girafe(code = print(p),
           options = list(
             opts_hover(css = "fill:red;cursor:pointer;"),
             opts_selection(type = "single", css = "fill:red;")
           )
           )
  })

  output$dt_ <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
})

ui.R
library(ggiraph)
library(htmltools)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=12,
           includeScript(path = "set_search_val.js"),
           h4("click a point, the data table will be filtered...")
           )
  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(width=6,
      girafeOutput("plot_")
    ),
    column(width=6,
           DT::dataTableOutput("dt_")
    )
  )
))

Can it be adapted (with js??) to my case?
Thank you!
